# is there a way to read only new (unread) messages in kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

in consumer when subscribed to a topic and start consuming messages it read the messages from the the beginning is there any way to read only unread messages ? this is the code i used for consuming the messages.

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
  props.put("group.id", "test");
  props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
  props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
  props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
  props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
  props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

  KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

  //Kafka Consumer subscribes list of topics here.
  consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

  while (true) {
      ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
      for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value= %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off auto.commit and manually commit each message offset after your app has successfully read it. That way if the app crashes it will restart at exactly the last committed offset.

Answer (score 0):

i have try your code, and it read only unread messages. what's your client version and server version?